# Uncaught TypeError: t.waypoint is not a function at HTMLHeadingElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How can I solve this I am just tried to take this I have tried many ways but still doesn't work please help me **

[image]

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ -->
<!-- way_points.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-XJuslujM3cGzRZGiSi/KNSdk58uORO/mmrEQNjVtb5k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- counter_up.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-JtQPj/3xub8oapVMaIijPNoM0DHoAtgh/gwFYuN5rik=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.count').counterUp({
        delay: 10,
        time: 3000
    })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There could be two possibilities; 1) either you have multiple jquery lib references or 2)  count element isn't present during execution.

Comment: Use this script:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js" integrity="sha256-jDnOKIOq2KNsQZTcBTEnsp76FnfMEttF6AV2DF2fFNE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>